# Where is the ESAPI documentation located?

Tags: owasp, esapi

I'm interested in ESAPI to use in a production environment.

Is there any official documentation on how to setup properly a web application, and if so, where?

Comment: Do you mean https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java or https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Enterprise_Security_API?

Comment: There are both the same right ? I mean the java library.

Comment: Yes, I meant that these two links are the best you can have as a documentation for ESAPI. As I understood, ESAPI is more a toolkit than a framework for a web application

Comment: That's very poor documentation.

Comment: The project (3.x) is not really active, as of today, the last _code_ commit was authored on Nov 20, 2013 ([79e7704](https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java/commit/79e7704868bb513ef1879082070f5a523f2f5d37)). There seem to be _only_ one contributor: "Chris Schmidt". The [_legacy_ project](https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy) seem to be more active, but the doc is still poor. It is provided _as is_.

Comment: The legacy project has seen a few bugfixes since 2013, but all have been quite minor, and active development isn't occurring.  There were over 200+ open issues on googlecode before it went away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ESAPI has good intentions, it is referenced de facto in OWASP Top 10 issues.

However its main development is not really active. The library is provided *as is*.

There are two Java libraries depending on the versions:

- [OWASP Enterprise Security API for Java](https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java): version >= 3.x

  - Maintained by one contributor (Chris Schmidt), [last code commit](https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java/commit/79e7704868bb513ef1879082070f5a523f2f5d37) (as of today) was on Nov 20, 2013.
- [Enterprise Security API for Java (Legacy)](https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy): version <= 2.x

  - Maintained by at least 3 contributors, [last code commit](https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/commit/20438dbae5ecf8a51f454f38d1e0525fe4b61eb6) (as of today) was on May 30, 2015.

There is a wish to have documentation (https://www.owasp.org/index.php/ESAPI_Documentation), especially: [How to Use ESAPI in a New Application](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/ESAPI_Documentation#How_to_Use_ESAPI_in_a_New_Application).

But currently, it is really light...

As of March 2014 the project was downgraded away from flagship status (http://off-the-wall-security.blogspot.fr/2014/03/esapi-no-longer-owasp-flagship-project.html). (credits to avgvstvs)

If you still want to learn ESAPI, the best you can have currently:

- The ESAPI swing set, a "web application which demonstrates the many uses of the ESAPI" (https://www.owasp.org/index.php/ESAPI_Swingset)
- The tests of the legacy version (https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/tree/master/src/test/java/org/owasp/esapi).
- The wiki of the legacy version (https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Enterprise_Security_API)
- The mailing list archives (http://lists.owasp.org/pipermail/esapi-dev/)

The [README](https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java/blob/master/README.md) on the new version annonce new stuff to come:

> 2 Sept 2014 - We are gearing up to get some great stuff done at AppSecUSA in Denver this month. We'll be announcing our schedule and where we'll be at the conference soon! Stay tuned!

Maybe the doc will arrive one day...

Comment: This answer is the best.  I think you should add this. As of March 2014 the project was downgraded away from flagship status: http://off-the-wall-security.blogspot.com/2014/03/esapi-no-longer-owasp-flagship-project.html

Comment: Thanks for the link @avgvstvs, is is valuable information, I didn't know it. Unless it bothers you, I will also mention ESAPI_Swingset in my answer, to make it more complete

Comment: Go ahead, its all the same to me.

Comment: @superbob is ESAPI currently used nowadays (2019)? If not, do you know what have replaced this framework? And if so... are there any migration steps documentation to do that?

Comment: @FedericoPiazza, AFAIK it is not used currently. I don't use it in either personal or professional projects.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to learn secure programming with ESAPI, check out the ESAPI swing set:  https://www.owasp.org/index.php/ESAPI_Swingset

However, as superbob has pointed out, you probably shouldn't use it in new production applications.